# How i change Scrapy to crawl on onion links?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I try to crawl on the darknet forum using Scrapy, I tried to change the Scrapy setting.
I am using python 2.7
someone can help me??

Comment: Have you [checked existing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrapy%5D+tor)?